# How to make my character walk by clicking and holding the mouse button?

Tags: unreal-4, mouse, blueprints

I created an Action Mapping using the right mouse button as a reference.

The Action Map is called "Andar" (walk in english).

**In the character code, I call this Action Mapping and in it I make the character walk by clicking the right mouse button (on Floor):**

[image]

But I would like the character to continue walking if the player clicked the right mouse button and held.

Like Set Destination (action mapping from Unreal).

**Other places I searched:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AIPPXGFkjF0

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/134746/hold-button-for-few-sec-and-play-event.html

It's a simple problem, but I can't find anything about. Not exactly. The problems I found in my search are not the same as my problem. Even changing the words and terms I was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With the help of the answer to this question:**

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/438398/a-simple-question-about-click-press-hold.html

I discovered to solve my problem.

- Add a boolean variable
- Set it to true every time the mouse button is pressed
- Set it to false every time the mouse button is released
- Insert a While Loop that only ends when the boolean variable is false.

**Code:**

[image]