# How to get the actor to follow the mouse while clicking and holding?

Tags: movement, unreal-4, mouse

I am trying to do the top down project from scratch.

**I can already get the actor to move toward the mouse click:**

[image]

Only I need to keep clicking several times to change its path and keep walking indefinitely.

I would like to know how to keep it moving while I hold the mouse button.

**In the previous version (4.21) this code below fit perfectly, so I managed to do that (the condition was a variable that only became false when I released the mouse button):**

[image]

But now I can't make this connection (4.22).

I searched for some functions and even searched the new documentation for this loop (While Loop), but nothing worked.

**Link (While Loop BP UE4):**

https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Blueprints/UserGuide/FlowControl/index.html#whileloop

---

**Player Blueprint:**

[image]

---

**As I could do this before, you can see in the answer to this question:**

[How to make my character walk by clicking and holding the mouse button?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/173987/how-to-make-my-character-walk-by-clicking-and-holding-the-mouse-button/174011#174011)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do it in Tick ?

You still can set the boolean variable on input action - and then use EventTick with conjunction of delay and send the player to the mouse location.